# Extracting and Filtering Through Items on a List (JS)

Tags: javascript, list, filter, extract

I'm new to Javascript, so apologies if this is a bit of an amateur question.

I want to be able to search through a list and pick out several items based on properties listed with the target items.

For example, let's say I have the following list:

```
<ul>
<li> Round Red Apple </li>
<li> Round Purple Grape </li>
<li> Round Yellow Lemon </li>
<li> Long Yellow Banana </li>
<li> Long Green Cucumber </li>
<li> Round Red Tomato </li>
</ul>
```

Each item is listed with two properties. How  would I, for instance, extract all the round items (Apple, Grape, Lemon, Tomato) and then display only these items (not the properties) elsewhere on a webpage, let's say in `<div id="display"></div>` ?

A little more complicated, how would I extract all the round items but only the ones that aren't also red (Grape, Lemon)?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all `li` items and check the value using [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) function and store in separate array to process later.

Sample code using [JQuery each() function](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var filteredItems = [];
$('li').each(function(i, item)
{
     var itemName = $(item).html();
     if(itemName.startsWith('Round'))
     {
          filteredItems.add(itemName);
     }
});
```

Now you can iterate `filteredItems` to append the items in desired `div`.

```
var container = $('#display');
$.each(filteredItems, function(i, item)
{
    container.append("<div>" + item + "</div");
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can do it in the same manner with JavaScript as well.

Try with :

- [JavaScript for loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) for iteration.
- [JavaScript getElementsByTagName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp) for getting all `li` item
- [JavaScript appendChild()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) for appending dynamic `div` in another `div`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately I don't know much at all about JQuery, so I really don't understand your code very well. But I'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: you can do it plain javascript as well in the same manner. you can use [JavaScript for loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)